# how to select only those lines which have same string in all columns with first line of different header in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have a text file with 200 columns like:

```
sample1 0 12 11 23 12
sample2 3 16 89 12 0
sample3 0  0  0  0 0 
sample4 33 22 0  0 0
sample5 0  0  0  0 0
```

And I want only those lines which have only 0 from column 2 to 6. desired out put is:

```
sample3 0  0  0  0 0 
sample5 0  0  0  0 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this, for example:

```
$ awk '!$2 && !$3 && !$4 && !$5 && !$6' file
sample3 0  0  0  0 0 
sample5 0  0  0  0 0
```

Which is the same as:

```
$ awk '!($2 || $3 || $4 || $5 || $6)' file
sample3 0  0  0  0 0 
sample5 0  0  0  0 0
```

---

As per your comment

> that is for example but i want to do that from column 2 to 200th

This can be a way:

```
$ awk '{for (i=2;i<=200;i++) if ($i) {next}}1' file
sample3 0  0  0  0 0 
sample5 0  0  0  0 0
```

Note that `$i` refers to the field in the position `i`. `$i` is true when it has got a "true" value. Hence, `$i` will be false when it is `0`.

Based on that approach, we loop through all values. In case one value is True, meaning not `0`, then we do `next`, which means that the line is not analyzed any more. For the rest of the cases (2nd to 200th column being `0` or empty), the `next` is not accomplished so it interprets the `1`, which makes `{print $0}` to be executed.

Comment: Dear fedorqui i mentioned that there is 200 columns , so it would not be convinient to write 200 times !$2 to !$200. i m seeking some other way sothat i need not to do like this one.

Comment: You say `i want only those lines which have only 0 from column 2 to 6`, so there is no need to check the rest of the columns if the condition just have to do with 2nd to 6th.

Comment: that is for example but i want to do that from column 2 to 200th.

Comment: OK so then indicate it in the question. I updated my answer with a `for` loop, see if it works now.

Comment: Thanx  fedorqui, its working , but will u plz explain that how it is working and taking the condition of '0' .

Comment: @aksg24 is it clear to you the answer? I added some explanation. Consider accepting the answer if so.